# Adding an Array multiple times in the DB via Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having an issue producing this array multiple times upon how many coupons purchased.

Now it looks like

```
$coupon_array = array(
    'user_id'=>$_POST["user_id"],
    'mergent_id'=>$_POST["merchant_id"],
    'deals_id'=>$_POST["deal_id"],
    'order_id'=>$order_id,
    'secret'=>$secret,
    'expire_time'=>$time,
    'create_time'=>$time,
    'status'=>1
   );

   $this->common_model->insertData('coupon', $coupon_array);
```

But i have a post value such as:

```
"quantity"=>$_POST["quantity"]
```

and i would like to produce this X times. Example:

```
$quantity x $this->common_model->insertData('coupon', $coupon_array);
```

Sorry for my english, and i hope i explain this so it's understandable... ;)

Another one! when we insert the coupons they all have the same md5($secret), is it possible to have that also with all the different code...

```
 $secret = md5($secret);


   $coupon_array = array(
    'user_id'=>$_POST["user_id"],
    'mergent_id'=>$_POST["merchant_id"],
    'deals_id'=>$_POST["deal_id"],
    'order_id'=>$order_id,
    'secret'=>$secret,
    'expire_time'=>$time,
    'create_time'=>$time,
    'status'=>1
   );
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if I understand what you want, you can use `for`, but that's obvious:

```
for($i=0; $i<$this->input->post('quantity');$i++) {
    $coupon_array['secret'] = md5($coupon_array['secret'].$i);
    $this->common_model->insertData('coupon', $coupon_array);
}
```

Also, never use `$_POST["..."]` in CodeIgniter, use only `$this->input->post('...')` as it escapes properly. More info about `input` class can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).

Comment: this should work but I kind of wonder why quantity isn't just a database field

Comment: @JohnB I wondered myself for a bit, but then understood that maybe every element should be processed separately, like he has status field, a customer buys 10 elements, 5 of which are processed and have status changed, while 5 remain with original status. It might not be the best design, but it's easier to maintain that way :)

Comment: Another issue, we have a $secret code generated for each coupon via md5() but now it's adding all coupons with the same md5 ;) See above..

Comment: @HafsteinnMárMásson I have updated my answer, now they will have different `$secret` fields

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i<$quanity; $i++) {
       $this->common_model->insertData('coupon', $coupon_array);
  }
```